# Durandal viewLocator/compose binding redundantly reports a 404 error

Tags: javascript, durandal

I'm composing a set of views and viewmodels and Durandal looks in the wrong place for one of the views, generating a 404 error (and a ghastly red-text message in the HTML saying the view could not be found) and then a second or two later looks in the right place for the view and renders it correctly.

I have no idea where to even begin to troubleshoot this because I am composing four other elements on the screen in the exact same way and those behave correctly.

Here's what the parent view looks like:

```
<div class="file-browser-container" data-bind="busy: folderTree.folderRootChanging">
{{#compose {model: entityContext, view: 'views/contextSelector.html' }}}
{{/compose}}    

<div class="file-pane-container u-clearfix" data-bind="if: entityContext.selectedAccount">        
    {{#compose {model: folderTree, view: 'views/folderTree.html', activationData: entityContext.selectedAccount} }}{{/compose}}

    {{#compose {model: fileList, view: 'views/fileList.html'} }}{{/compose}}

    {{#compose {model: fileUpload, view: 'views/fileUpload.html', activationData: { folderTree: folderTree, fileListing: fileList}} }}{{/compose}}
</div>
```

The folderTree.html view then does the following additional compose:

```
<section class="folder-view-pane" data-bind="busy: folderTreeUpdating">
<h4>Available Folders</h4>
<ul class="folder-node" data-bind="">
    {{#compose {model: currentFolderRoot, view: 'views/partial/folderNode.html', preserveContext: true}}}{{/compose}}
</ul>
```

I'm using knockout.punches (but please trust me, I have tried just using the standard ko container-less syntax too, that is not the issue.)

The folderNode composition is the one that is not working, durandal\require goes out to look for the view at "base/app/views/views/partial/folderNode.html" which is wrong, and then correctly looks in "base/app/views/partial/folderNode.html" so our users are getting a really gnarly flash effect as the view goes from error to the rendered view.

I have tried moving the view/html out into the views directory with the others and it makes no difference. Infuriatingly, when I change the composition to look for view: 'partial/folderNode.html' require then goes to look in 'base/app/partial/folderNode.html' and just plain fails.

Any insight as to why Durandal would choose to look in the wrong place? Is it related to this compose being inside of another composed element?

Lastly, we are using:

```
viewLocator.useConvention();
```

In the main.js file.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but from the same problem, I've found a solution to avoid RequireJS 404 :
you have to add a member function to your composing object (folderTree, fileList...) named getView(). That member could return a string to be interpreted as the view url, as mentioned here :
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Location.html
good luck!